# How can I add rows during operation with SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my first Android/sql project and I'm creating an attendance app wih two databases. DatabaseHelper has a table with the list of students/professors. The other one called coursesDatabase has one table that stores names of classes, and their info. The issue I'm having trouble with is that I want to make table for each class that logs attendance for that specific class, starting with COL1=STUDENT_NAME, then adding each COL2=LAST_NAME, COL3=DATE1, COL4=DATE2, etc... with each date column being created every time the professor creates an attendance section. Here is my code, excluding irrelevant completed methods:

```
public class CoursesDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static CoursesDatabase cd = null;

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "course_manager.db";
public static final String COURSES_TABLE_NAME = "COURSES";
public static final String KEY_ID = "ID";                         //column index 0
public static final String KEY_NAME= "COURSE_NAME";               //column index 1
public static final String KEY_CODE = "COURSE_CODE";              //column index 2
public static final String KEY_HOUR = "COURSE_HOUR";              //column index 3
public static final String KEY_MINUTE = "COURSE_MINUTE";          //column index 4
public static final String KEY_INSTRUCTOR = "COURSE_INSTRUCTOR";  //column index 5
public static final String IS_ON = "IS_ON";                       //column index 6

private CoursesDatabase(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    deleteAll();
    addCourse(new Course("354", "Software Engineering", "12345", 10, 30, "doctor doc"));
    addCourse(new Course("237", "CompSci 2", "13346", 11, 0, "john doe"));
}

public static CoursesDatabase getInstance(Context context){
    if (cd == null){
        cd = new CoursesDatabase(context);
    }
    return cd;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase cd) {
    final String SQL_CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + COURSES_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            KEY_ID          +   " TEXT NOT NULL, "  +   // column 0
            KEY_NAME        +   " TEXT NOT NULL, "  +   // column 1
            KEY_CODE        +   " TEXT NOT NULL, "  +   // column 2
            KEY_HOUR        +   " INT, "            +   // column 3
            KEY_MINUTE      +   " INT, "            +   // column 4
            KEY_INSTRUCTOR  +   " TEXT,"            +   // column 5
            IS_ON           +   "INT DEFAULT 0);";      // column 6

    cd.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER_TABLE);
}

//Creates a table to log attendance for each class
String KEY_STUDENT_FIRST_NAME = "First_Name";
String KEY_STUDENT_LAST_NAME = "Last_Name";
public void newClassTable(SQLiteDatabase cd, Course course){
    String CLASS_TABLE_NAME = course.getId() + "-" + course.getName() + "-" + course.getHour() + ":" + course.getMinute();

    final String SQL_CREATE_CLASS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            KEY_STUDENT_FIRST_NAME     +   " STRING NOT NULL, " +  // column 0
            KEY_STUDENT_LAST_NAME      +   " STRING NOT NULL);";   // column 1
    cd.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CLASS_TABLE);
}

//takes the attendance of a student in course table. If the student does not exist in the course table, the student is then added.
public boolean attendStudentInCourse(Student student, Course course) {
    SQLiteDatabase cd = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //if professor has not turned on the course yet exit
    if (!course.isAvailable()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

So my question is what methods do I use in order to create a new column at the end of the class table when the professor clicks on "new session" for that class? And how would I be able to update that specific last row when a student attempts the `attendStudentInCourse()` method?

Comment: That sounds like a horrible design. Use a table that stores rows like `(class_id, student_id, date, attended)` or the like instead to track attendance.

Comment: I considered that, but I'm planning on making it so that professors can easily view and modify the attendance for each class and be able to export the table to an excel file that can be easily used for elearning, and having that design would just require more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is what methods do I use in order to create a new
>   column at the end of the class table when the professor clicks on "new
>   session" for that class?

You can add a column to a table (with some conditions) by using

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table_name> ADD COLUMN <you_column_definition(e)>
```

- Note you'd use the **execSQL** method as there isn't a convenience method due to the rarity that ALTER would be used.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) ***read this for the conditions/limitations.***

> And how would I be able to update that specific last row when a
>   student attempts the attendStudentInCourse() method?

Assuming you meant column rather than row then

Noting that you can use `DEFAULT <default_value>` to set a default value which would be applied to all existing rows.

If setting a default value (I would guess that a new session would initially have 0 students in the course) doesn't suit then you can use an UPDATE query.

If you meant row then :-

However, adding a column does not add a row, the added column is applied to all rows.

---

Saying all that the design could probably be improved to:-

- a) have a single database that utilises relationships as SQLite is a Relational Database Management System (RDMS) and is designed to cope admirably with relationships between tables.
- b) have relationships to exclude the complexities of varying numbers of columns or lists within a column (adding columns and thus having a dynamic hard to read schema).
- c) Normalise some factors e.g. the instructor, as this appears to have to be entered per row and may well be duplicated and be inefficient.
- for example *Professor Ihavea Longname* will require over 25 bytes every time it is stored, and up to 25 bytes may need to be inspected when a search/comparison is made against the row.

  - If you instead had an instructor table then you'd only need to store the reference to the instructor (an alias of the rowid would very likely be very suitable column to reference, as is why the normally hidden rowid column exists), then the 25_ bytes would be stored just once, whilst the reference (approx 8 bytes max (if you have billions of instructors) approx 1 byte for up to 127 instructors) only would be stored saving space, reducing IO, increasing what can be cached.

### Example (using raw SQL)

As an example perhaps consider the following which uses :-

- a **role** table for roles (instructor student) (i.e. a person has a role) so there is
- a **person** table for all people (their relationship (one role to many people) determining what they do (instruct (instructor), be taught (student), help instruct (Instructor aid) or administer)

  - New roles can be dynamically added if the need arises
- a **course** table that has static information about a course, name, code time
- and **attendance** table that is a mapping table that stores all attendance information (all attendance registers in one).

-- Note single database with multiple tables with relationship mapping aka referencing

-- Note single database with multiple tables with relationship mapping aka referencing

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS role;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS course;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attendance;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS proposed_attendance_list;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS non_attendance_list;

-- Create the role table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS role (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, role);
-- Add some roles
-- NOTE _id column is not specified so SQLite will assign a unqiue value 
-- assigned value will likely be 1, then likely 2, then likely 3........9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (highest)
-- NOTE no need for AUTOINCREMENT keyword and the resultant performance loss
-- NOTE _id is the column name that best suits Android (e.g. Cursor Adapters need this column name)
INSERT INTO ROLE (role) VALUES 
    ('Instructor'), -- id 1
    ('Student'), -- id 2
    ('Instructor Aid '), -- id 3
    ('Administrator') -- id 4
    -- !!!NOTE!!! you would not typically assume specific id
;

-- Create the Person table (Person will have a role - for simplicity of demo single role assumed)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, role INTEGER);

INSERT INTO person (name,role) VALUES
    ('Professor Plum',1), -- Instructor id = 1
    ('Tom Brown',2), -- Student id = 2
    ('Mary Smith',2), -- Student  id = 3
    ('Sue Barnes',2), -- Student id = 4
    ('Ty Pit',4), -- Admin id = 5
    ('Dr. J M Hardy',1), -- Instructor id = 6
    ('Matilda Dance',2), -- Student id = 7
    ('Fred Bloggs',3) -- Aid id = 8

;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    course_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    course_code TEXT NOT NULL, 
    course_hour TEXT NOT NULL, 
    course_minute TEXT, 
    course_time, 
    course_instructor INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO course (course_name, course_code, course_hour, course_minute, course_instructor) VALUES
    ('MATHS BASIC','M001','10','30',6), -- Maths with instructor Dr. J M Hardy id = 1
  ('MATHS APPLIED', 'M101','12','30',6), -- Applied Maths instructor Dr. J M Hardy id =2 
  ('MATHS ADVANCED','M011','11','00',1) -- Advanced Maths instructor Professor Plum id =3
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attendance (course_reference INTEGER, person_reference INTEGER, attended INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (course_reference, person_reference));
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES
    (1,6,0), -- Dr J M Hardy should attend (attended 0 = should attend, -1 if did not attend, 1 if did attend) course MATCHS BASIC
    (1,3,0), -- Mary Should attent Basic maths
    (1,7,0), -- Matilda should attend basic maths
    (1,8,0), -- Aid Fred should attend basic maths
    (3,1,1), -- Advanced maths Plum attended (taught it)
    (3,2,-1), -- Advanced maths Tom Brown missed
    (3,3,1), -- Advanced maths mary attended
    (3,8,1), -- Aid Fred attended
    (2,4,1), -- Applied Maths Sue attended
    -- (2,4,0) WOULD BE DUPLICATE SO NOT ALLOWED (INSERT OR IGNORE would skip, Note android SQliteDatabase insert method uses INSERT OR IGNORE)
    (2,3,0), -- Mary didn't attend as such but not flagged as did not attend (could just use 0 to indicate did not attend)
    (2,7,1), -- Applied Maths Matilda attended
    (2,6,0), -- Dr Hardy should attend
    (2,1,0), -- Prof Plum should attend
    (2,8,0) -- Fred Bloggs Admin should attend
;

-- Course attendace example listing the course details, the number of attendees and the list of attendees
-- Create as a view so that it can be resued (only need to type it out once)
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS proposed_attendance_list AS 
    SELECT 
        course.course_name, 
        course.course_code, 
        course.course_hour||':'||course.course_minute AS CourseTime, 
        count(attended) AS proposed_attendance, 
        group_concat(Person.name,' ,') AS peeople 
    FROM Course 
        JOIN attendance ON course._id = attendance.course_reference
        JOIN person ON attendance.person_reference = person._id
        JOIN role ON person.role = role._id
    -- GROUP BY course_hour, course_minute
    -- HAVING
    GROUP BY course_code
    ORDER BY course.course_code,role._id
;
-- Initial proposed course attendance
SELECT * FROM proposed_attendance_list;
-- Change some course codes
UPDATE course SET course_code = 'M201' WHERE course_code = 'M101';
UPDATE course SET course_code = 'M111' WHERE course_code = 'M011';
-- Modifed proposed course attendance
SELECT * FROM proposed_attendance_list;
```

- Note comments (-- )

### Results

#### 1. Initial Proposed Course Attendance

[image]

#### 2. After Course name changes

[image]

### Regarding changing attendance

First another view to write a letter re non-attendance as a demo

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS non_attendance_list AS
    SELECT course_name, 
        course_code, 
        Person.name, 
        Person.role, 
        'Dear '||person.name||' our records show that you did''t attend Course '||course_code||' '||course_name||' rest of letter' AS letter_to_send
    FROM attendance
        JOIN course ON course_reference = course._id
        JOIN Person ON person_reference = Person._id
        JOIN Role ON Person.role = role._id
    WHERE attendance.attended < 1
    ORDER BY course_code
;

-- Initial letters
SELECT letter_to_send FROM non_attendance_list;
```

### Result

[image]

### Change attendance Example

```
-- Set Mary as having attended M001 Basic maths
UPDATE attendance SET attended = 1 
    WHERE course_reference = (SELECT _id FROM course WHERE course_code = 
        'M001' -- value that would be changed to suit
    )
        AND person_reference = (SELECT _id FROM person WHERE name =
        'Mary Smith' -- value that would be changed to suit
        )
;
-- Letters after update
SELECT letter_to_send FROM non_attendance_list;
```

### Result (No Letter to Mary re M001)

[image]